# Django enctype=multipart/form-data on localhost returns white screen

Tags: python, django

I am running django on a pipenv virtual machine on my MacBook on localhost:8000. I created a django form to upload an image with enctype=multipart/form-data.

When clicking on submit, on all browsers, I get a white page. Checking the browsers network status, its a 400 error, and in Firefox I get:

`The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.`

When removing the enctype, everything works fine - but of course the image isn't uploaded.
The error seems to occur before any data manipulation on my side.

On a remote development server, everything works fine with and without encoding - so it seems to be related to my development environment.

Unfortunately I can't find any hints on why this error occurs. Does anybody have a hint or an idea on how to solve this?

**More Information**

- Macbook Pro Catalina 10.15.3
- Django 2.2
- Running with the django internal server (manage.py runserver)

**Update**

The same issue occurs on the django admin edit page ( http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/1/change/ ). I noticed there is a multipart encoded form as well. Submitting this results in the same error.

**Update 2**

The issue has been found. I have been installing the new app with the requirements.txt of our project and found that the library `channels` was outdated.

*Thanks for your help!*

Comment: Coule you please share your code detials, please?

Comment: I added a small update that explains the same situation happening in default django functionality. It doesn't seem to be related to specific code as probably to some server issues? Unfortunately I don't know where or how to start debugging.

Comment: You share your code...in here

Comment: I created a new project with django. No code from my side. I go to the admin panel. I click on edit user (superadmin). I click on save. Error occurs. No requirements in pip, no custom code. If there is anything I miss that I could share, please let me know.

Comment: OK. what is an error, just share your screenshot please

Comment: The encoding warning is not the issue.  Please provide an [mre]

Comment: Continuing debugging, I found the issue and updated the post accordingly. Thanks for your help!